Why are some submission IDs missing in OpenReview?
I use OpenReview for a conference as a program chair. I see the list of submissions sorted by ID.  I notice that some submission IDs are missing, e.g. below there is 14, 17, 24 but 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 are missing. Why?

There are no Withdrawn Submissions and no Desk Rejected Submissions:

